# mvc application hosted on local IIS getting redirected to local host

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, localhost

[![this is the url I am trying to access... but it is redirecting to local host][1]][1]

As shown in the image, I am trying to access the URL but it is redirecting to my localhost:44367 which is my project URL
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8d1g.jpg

Comment: Learn how to use Chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network and then you can study where the redirection comes from.

Comment: Please use cmd to ping the server to ensure data exchange, then access your localhsot:44367 to check what application is deployed in local IIS. and check url rewrite rule of the application's web.config. Maybe some rules or configuration in local IIS redirect your request but you forgot. Last check the webconfig of mvc application.Some path configurations in webconfig may also cause redirection. For example, some paths set during development are http://localhost......